# Same Category attributes in an entity to a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties, attributes, propertyinfo

> I have an entity witch has some properties. i have used category
>   attribute to categorize similar properties together.`

```
       [System.ComponentModel.Category("cat_name1")]
       public string propname1 { get; set; }
       [System.ComponentModel.Category("cat_name2")]
       public string propname2 { get; set; }
```

> I want to get these properties to a dictionary object key as category
>   and value a property list

```
Dictionary<string, List<PropertyInfo>> variable_name= TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(new entityClass())
.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
    .ToDictionary(s =>s.Category,TypeDescriptor.GetProperti[enter image description here][1]es(new entityClass())
    .Cast<PropertyDescriptor()
    .GroupBy(p=>p.Category).ToList<PropertyInfo>());
```

> im getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one approach that will create `Dictionary<string, List<string>`. Keys will be categy names and values will be list of strings (in case you have two or more properties with same category).

```
EntityClass entityClass = new EntityClass();
entityClass.propname1 = "abc";
entityClass.propname2 = "def";

System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entityClass);
var dict = pdc.OfType<PropertyDescriptor>().GroupBy(x => x.Category).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(p => p.GetValue(entityClass).ToString()).ToList());
```

**EDIT**: 
I'm not sure if this is the result you wanted, because of poor question format/structure. Please try to explain a bit better next time..

Comment: It works!!! Thanks... !!!
instead of property value i wanted property names.. but i figured it... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> This is what i have done..

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, AttributeCollection>> testingSectionFields =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(new PP_MainDataEntity())
                .OfType<PropertyDescriptor>().ToList()
                .GroupBy(cat => cat.Category)
                .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c1 => c1.ToDictionary(fld => fld.Name, fld1 => fld1.Attributes));
```

> wich retreives entity properties -> group them by category attribute
>   -> get all attributes specific to that property :)